# Canopy Silent Installation

Tags: enthought

We want to use Canopy in our University. Now i need a option for a silent installation. Hopefully this does exists. ;-) I'm able to install Canopy silent with the msi package with this command:

msiexec.exe /i canopy.msi /q

But the problem is that this is a user install. I can't find any Option to install Canopy for **All Users**. Have someone any idee?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but it looks as if adding `ALLUSERS=1` should do it. Also, you must explicitly run the command in a terminal with escalated privileges, as described at https://support.enthought.com/entries/23736288-Windows-on-some-systems-admin-users-cannot-immediately-install-for-all-users-

Finally, whether you are installing for one user or many, note that running the MSI only installs Canopy Core. For a user to actually use the Canopy application or Canopy User Python, you must also run the application's initial setup. For scripting this, see this section of the user's guide: http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/canopy-cli.html . You might find [the final section](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/canopy-cli.html#scenario-creating-a-system-wide-canopy-install) most pertinent to your requirements.